# VisualSVN branch version

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

If I'm working on a repo with a trunk and one or more branches, is there a visual way to determine which branch I have loaded? I don't see an option in Visual Studio or TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 3):

The repository URL of your current working copy is displayed on the right side of Visual Studio's toolbar on the top.

[image]